# Remote Desktop from Mac -> Rpi

Tags: remote, macos

I have to monitor several computers for my job and use Remote desktop to view multiple screens at once. The problem is I can't just sit there and watch the screens, and even if I do the screen can't show all of the computers I need to monitor. So I was hoping to use some Raspberry pi's to help out. The first step to to get the raspberry pi to view the mac books.

Is there a way to use remote desktop (the Mac program) on Raspberry pi (not connect to the raspberry pi but run the program on the raspberry pi os)?  I need the Raspberry pi to make the connection to the mac books, not the other way around. (found a lot of tutorials about connecting To your raspberry pi From your mac but I need it the other way around.)

I am quite new to Raspberry pi but I'm interested in making this work.

Comment: What "remote desktop (the Mac program)"? The Microsoft program is to enable Windows to access Mac.

Answer (score 2):

There is something called VNC that you can use.  It is supported natively in Raspbian, and it appears that [on a Mac it is also supported quite readily](https://support.jumpdesktop.com/hc/en-us/articles/216425923-Mac-How-do-I-enable-the-VNC-Server-built-into-the-Mac-).

Also a more secure method is SSH - but it really depends what you need to do with it.  [Here is a guide on that](https://www.booleanworld.com/access-mac-ssh-remote-login/).

Keep in mind that Raspbian is a form of Debian - meaning mainstream Linux methods of access are all available.

Hopefully this gets you started.  Moving forward, there should be a ton of tutorials online as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the Pi's are connecting to the Macbooks,  the Macbooks need to run a VNC server, 
and that can be started by:

```
- Go to Apple Logo and Select System Preferences
- Open the Sharing 'folder'
- Click and enable Screen Sharing checkbox
```

This will say something like:

```
Other users can access your computer's screen at vnc://192.168.0.33/ or by 
looking for “YOURMACNAME” in the Finder sidebar.
```

Once that is set, you can exit and go to anyone of your Pi's, and install a VNC Client, which there are a several... RealVNC, TightVNC to name a few.